# I don't want to use InstanceOf multiple times or a Visitor pattern

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm looking for some help on a Java (1.8) problem.
I have a class (i'll put it bellow) that have multiple methods with the same name using different types of parameters but all inheritant of the same interface.
I wanted to call this method using a variable from the interface and java to use the adapted method mainly to avoid using multiple instanceof ... or the visitor pattern that would in my opinion greatly improve code complexity which i would avoid.

Here is the class :

```
public class BoxAdapterToRenderer {
public static Node createRenderer(Fighter fighter){
    Rectangle fighterRenderer = new Rectangle();
    fighterRenderer.setHeight(50);
    fighterRenderer.setWidth(50);
    Image im = new Image(Constants.ruleReader.getFighterImageURL(fighter.getName()),false);
    fighterRenderer.setFill(new ImagePattern(im));
    return fighterRenderer;
}

public static Node createRenderer(Bomb bomb){
    Rectangle bombRenderer = new Rectangle();
    bombRenderer.setHeight(50);
    bombRenderer.setWidth(50);
    Image im = new Image(Constants.ruleReader.getBombImageURL(),false);
    bombRenderer.setFill(new ImagePattern(im));
    return bombRenderer;
}

public static Node createRenderer(Mine mine){
    Rectangle mineRenderer = new Rectangle();
    mineRenderer.setHeight(50);
    mineRenderer.setWidth(50);
    Image im = new Image(Constants.ruleReader.getMineImageURL(),false);
    mineRenderer.setFill(new ImagePattern(im));
    return mineRenderer;
}

public static Node createRenderer(StaminaPad staminaPad){
    Rectangle staminaPadRenderer = new Rectangle();
    staminaPadRenderer.setHeight(50);
    staminaPadRenderer.setWidth(50);
    Image im = new Image(Constants.ruleReader.getStaminaPadImageURL(),false);
    staminaPadRenderer.setFill(new ImagePattern(im));
    return staminaPadRenderer;
}
```

here is an exemple of a call :

```
Box box = board.getGrid()[i][j];
BoxAdapterToRenderer.createRenderer(box)
```

So here my interface is Box and my different inheritant classes are Fighter, bomb, mine etc...
here java don't want to compile because it doesn't detect a createRenderer with a Box type parameter

Also I would like to add that Box and its differents inheritants are part of the model of a global MVC pattern the createRenderer method here is called in the view and the model shouldn't be conserned by the view at all,
typically defining the createRenderer method in Box isn't a solution.

Comment: For me it seems like the Box interface should have method createRenderer, and classes Mine, StaminaPad, Bomb, Fighter would implement them in different way (instead in BoxAdapterToRenderer class).

Comment: Thanks and sorry I've updated my question i forgot to mention about the MVC your solution can't work here.

Comment: Have a look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch . Probably not possible in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
interface Box
{
  Node createRenderer();
}

class Fighter implements Box
{

  @Override
  public Node createRenderer() {
    //TODO: implement this
    return null;
  }
}

class Bomb implements Box
{
  //TODO: implement this
  @Override
  public Node createRenderer() {
    return null;
  }
}

class Mine implements Box
{
  //TODO: implement this
  @Override
  public Node createRenderer() {
    return null;
  }
}

class StaminaPad implements Box
{
  //TODO: implement this
  @Override
  public Node createRenderer() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Example call:

```
Box box = board.getGrid()[i][j];
box.createRenderer();
```

You have the interface Box which describes the behaviour all boxes should have.
And then every class that implements this interface will have its own implementation of the methods that you defined. Assuming that the `board` contains different objects that implement the Box interface, then you can call the method .createRenderer() without needed to check which concrete implementation the objects have.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I've updated my question i forgot to mention about the MVC your solution can't work here.